# Trigonometry system - complex conjugate

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

I have the following function
$$e_n(t) = e^{2\pi int}, t \in R, n \in Z$$
Could anyone explain how one can go from this:
$$e_m(t) \bar e_n(t) $$
to
$$e^{-2\pi i(m - n)t}$$

Shouldn't it be $e^{2\pi i(m - n)t}$ instead of $e^{-2\pi i(m - n)t}$?

Comment: Where did you get this from? It might be a typo

Answer (score -1):

If $e_n(t)=e^{2πint}$, the conjugate is $\bar{e}_n(t)=e^{-2πint}$

Then

$e_m(t)\bar{e}_n(t)=e^{2πimt}e^{-2πint}=e^{-2πi(n-m)t}.$

Comment: I understand that part but should $e^{2πimt}e^{-2πint}=e^{2πi(m-n)t}$?

Comment: add the exponents

Comment: it doesn't answer my question! I know how to add exponents.

Comment: $a^n\cdot a^m = \underbrace{ \underbrace{a \times \cdots \times a}_n \times  \underbrace{a \times \cdots \times a}_m}_{n+m} = a^{n+m}$. Therefor $a^n \cdot a^m = a^{n+m} $